# How to make a silent installer using NSIS

Tags: nsis, silent-installer

There have 2 or more installer. One add from my PC and 1 or 2 installer download from that link. The installer which is add on my PC it's run manually but the installer which is dowload from that link, it's need to installer and run silently.

Answer (score 0):

Add `SilentInstall silent` to your script to force the installer to always be silent.

To force a 3rd-party NSIS installer to be silent, use /S:

```
installer.exe /S
```